# What was the command which makes MacPorts print the checksums

Tags: macports

I know there is an option which makes MacPorts print the checksum of the currently downloaded package files. All I get is:

```
port checksum current     
--->  Verifying checksums for atari800
Error: Checksum (rmd160) mismatch for atari800-4.2.0-src.tgz
Error: Checksum (sha256) mismatch for atari800-4.2.0-src.tgz
Error: Checksum (size) mismatch for atari800-4.2.0-src.tgz
Error: Failed to checksum atari800: Unable to verify file checksums
Error: See /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_Volumes_Samsung_Work_MacPorts_dports_emulators_atari800/atari800/main.log for details.
Error: Follow https://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets to report a bug.
Error: Processing of port atari800 failed
```

This is of course vitally important if you make a version bump and want to insert the new checksums into the Portfile.

However I forgot what the option is and can't find it in the documentation either. And yes I searched.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the end:

```sh
port -v checksum -d current
```

Comment: Single-dash single-letter flags like `-v` and `-d` go before the verb and can be combined, e.g. `port -v checksum` or `port -d checksum` or `port -d -v checksum` or `port -dv checksum`. `-d` is a superset of `-v` so all you need is `port -d checksum`.